# Fast method to find Schnorr group generator

Tags: cryptography, primes, gmp, number-theory, prime-factoring

To find [Schnorr group generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_group) I have to find three numbers p, q and r such that:

- p = qr + 1
- p and q are primes

It is very difficult to find q and r to meet all criteria in case when p and q should be very large primes.
I've tried to find q and r randomly using GNU GMP library, but no numbers I've found during 30 minutes on my laptop meet criteria described above.

Is there any fast method to find such numbers and Schorr group generator?

Thanks!

Comment: **UPD**: I found such method in chapter A1.1.2 of [current DSA spec](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips186-3/fips_186-3.pdf)

Comment: @Flipp: make your comment an answer and accept your own answer.

Comment: Better suited for [crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3):

I found such method in chapter A1.1.2 of [current DSA specification](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/fips/186/4/final).

The gist of the method described is to

1. pick the prime `q`;
2. pick a large value `X` (about the same size as the desired `p`);
3. compute `p = X - (X mod 2q) + 1` (i.e., now `p = 1 (mod 2q)`);
4. check whether `p` is prime.

Comment: Can you expand on this a bit? Your answer breaks if the link does. If you would, simply summarize the important points (or your answer is likely to be removed)

Comment: @TimPost: I'll put my implementation here as far as it will be ready.